# How can i select the most recent purchase by the Clients?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, greatest-n-per-group

In a database with several tables and relationships between them, I want to select only the most recent payment by the clients last year.

My query goes like this:

```
SELECT
  P.Name,
  EV.EventName,
  FN.Installments,
  FN.PurchaseValue,
  FN.DueDate

FROM ClientPrivate PF
JOIN Client P        ON P.PesControle = PF.PesControle
JOIN ClientClass CP  ON P.PesControle = CP.PesControle
JOIN EVENT EV        ON CP.EveControle = EV.EveControle 
JOIN Class cc        ON cc.CurControle = EV.CurControle   
JOIN Finance FN      ON FN.PesControle = P.PesControle
```

It returns the values I need, only I'd like to get only the most recent purchase by each client, instead of all of them.

I edited to help clarify. The 'Controle' columns are the keys.

Comment: Which column is the identifier for the client and the date?  It's not clear from your column names.

Comment: I guess `PesNome` is name and which one is date column?

Comment: Fin = End , Dia = Day , Nome = Name , thanks to google translator :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you date column is put that in the ORDER BY Clause of the ROW_NUMBER() function and you are good to go.

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT
  P.PesNome,
  EV.EveDescri,
  FN.FinTotParc,
  FN.FinVlrLiquido,
  FN.FinDiaVencto,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PesNome ORDER BY [DateColumn] DESC) rn

FROM PessoaFisica PF
JOIN Pessoa P        ON P.PesControle = PF.PesControle
JOIN CursoPessoa CP  ON P.PesControle = CP.PesControle
JOIN EVENTO EV       ON CP.EveControle = EV.EveControle 
JOIN Curso cc        ON cc.CurControle = EV.CurControle   
JOIN Financeiro FN   ON FN.PesControle = P.PesControle 
  )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `Financeiro.FinDiaVencto` is your purchase date, and that `Pessoa.PesControle` is a unique identifier for a person.  If not, you'll need to modify the query.  I'm using Google to translate Portuguese, and it's still not clear to me.

```
SELECT
  P.PesNome,
  EV.EveDescri,
  FN.FinTotParc,
  FN.FinVlrLiquido,
  FN.FinDiaVencto
FROM PessoaFisica PF
JOIN Pessoa P
  ON P.PesControle = PF.PesControle
JOIN CursoPessoa CP
  ON P.PesControle = CP.PesControle
JOIN EVENTO EV
  ON CP.EveControle = EV.EveControle 
JOIN Curso cc
  ON cc.CurControle = EV.CurControle   
JOIN Financeiro FN
  on FN.PesControle = P.PesControle 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM PessoaFisica PF_s
        JOIN Pessoa P_s
            ON P_s.PesControle = PF_s.PesControle
        JOIN CursoPessoa CP_s
            ON P_s.PesControle = CP_s.PesControle
        JOIN EVENTO EV_s
            ON CP_s.EveControle = EV_s.EveControle 
        JOIN Curso cc_s
            ON cc_s.CurControle = EV_s.CurControle   
        JOIN Financeiro FN_s
            on FN_s.PesControle = P_s.PesControle 
        WHERE P_s.PesControle = P.PesControle
        HAVING MAX(FN_s.FinDiaVencto) = FN.FinDiaVencto
    )
```

That should return the record with the most recent `Financeiro.FinDiaVencto` for each `Pessoa.PesControle`.  If you need it by course or by event(?) you'll need to modify the `WHERE` clause to join on those fields, too.

I'm not sure if that join to `PessoaFisica` is necessary either, but I included it because it could be eliminating records.  You *can* include a `GROUP BY` in the subquery, but it *should* be redundant.